# Get DLL caller info in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, dll

In a Delphi DLL need to establish the caller -- which may be a simple ".exe" or a DBMS runtime module -- which means it must obtain the command which is running in the process.

I know that **CmdLine** won't work, and probably **ParamStr(0)**, and cannot use "main window" based techniques as caller will sometimes not have a window.  I suspect that
**GetModuleHandle** is the starting point, but need assistance to get from there to command being executed.

Comment: Why can't you just have your caller tell you the information you need to know in a parameter?

Comment: You have to define "caller" in more precise way.

Answer (score 4):

I created a test dll:

```
library Project2;

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Winapi.Windows;

{$R *.res}

procedure DoStuff; stdcall;
begin
    ShowMessage(
            'ParamStr(0): '+ParamStr(0)+#13#10+
            'GetCommandLine: : '+GetCommandLine);
end;

exports
    DoStuff;
begin
end.
```

And then call it from a test application:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    module: HMODULE;
    doStuff: procedure; stdcall;
begin
    module := LoadLibrary('D:\Temp\Win32\Debug\Project2.dll');
    if module = 0 then
        RaiseLastOSError;
    try
        doStuff := GetProcAddress(module, 'DoStuff');

        if @doStuff = nil then
            raise Exception.Create('Could not find export "DoStuff"');

        DoStuff;
    finally
        FreeLibrary(module);
    end;
end;
```

And it sees the command line, using both:

- `ParamStr(0)`
- `GetCommandLine`

[image]

`GetCommandLine` obviously shows the entire command line, while `ParamStr(0)` is (by definition) just the process executable path.

Answer (score 1):

In fact `ParamStr(0)` will work fine. It is, on Windows, implemented with a call to the API function [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx), passing a value of `0` as the module handle. This retrieves the file name associated with the main executable module. This works just the same no matter that the call is made from a DLL or the main executable.

We don't really need to dig into the implementation if we would trust the Delphi documentation. Admittedly this can sometimes be a risky business! The documentation for [`ParamStr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ParamStr) says:

> ParamStr(0) returns the path and file name of the executing program (for example, `C:\TEST\MYPROG.EXE`).

If you need to know the arguments that were passed to the executable process, you can use `ParamStr` passing indices greater than zero. Or you could call `GetCommandLine` and parse the command line yourself.

Do beware that `GetCommandLine` will not always give the same executable file name as `GetModuleFileName`. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx) says:

> The name of the executable in the command line that the operating system provides to a process is not necessarily identical to that in the command line that the calling process gives to the CreateProcess function. The operating system may prepend a fully qualified path to an executable name that is provided without a fully qualified path.

All this feels a little dirty though. It might be cleaner to export an initialization function from the DLL and require callers to pass whatever information you need.

Comment: David, It was a "trust the Delphi documentation" issue that triggered this question.  Those docs say the global "CmdLine" variable is not valid in a DLL -- and that led me to believe "GetModuleFileName" was not usable (i.e. it would take some other series of arcane WinAPI calls to obtain the needed info).  BTW, the reason I cannot ask the caller to identify itself is that the calls will come from both code that can be recompiled, to accomodate a change, and code over a decade old which is no longer modifiable (while the DLL API is a substitute for a former one which didn't need to know).

Comment: If in doubt one can always consult the source code. Which I did. So now you can trust ParamStr(0).

Comment: ... Unless you are a beginner using the so-called "Starter" Edition, in which case you have no choice but to rely on the documentation (or ask someone else).  Just saying.  ;)

Comment: @BruceWeinel Are you still stuck?